# Настройка iptables для OpenVPN

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, nat, openvpn

Настраиваю OpenVPN на клиенте, создаю следующие правила iptables:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.128.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.128.0.0/24 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.128.0.0/24 -o wlan0 -j SNAT --to-source <myserverip>
```

В `net.ipv4.ip_forward и /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding` стоит 1.
Интернета как не было на клиенте, так и нет(( что делать?

Comment: Запускать tcpdump на интерфейсах и смотреть как проходят пакеты. вместо -j SNAT --to-source попробовать -j MASQUERADE, ей не надо указывать какой ip на пакеты ставить

Comment: на каком протоколе основана передача данных программой *openvpn* — tcp или udp?

Comment: -j MASQUERADE результатов не дал.

Comment: в tcpdump пакеты сначала проходят с клиента на сервер и обратно, а потом появляются строки типа 18:56:32.605354 IP 192.168.1.4.52530 > CPE-EG-SNR.lo.domain: 64294+ PTR? 1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, tcp

Comment: в вопросе приведены все правила netfilter-а?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да:) а какие-то еще надо добавить?...

Comment: надо не «добалять правила» (два из продемонстрированных, кстати, лишние), а смотреть, приходят ли пакеты, отправляются ли с правильным адресом назначения, возвращаются ли ответы, предаются ли ответы адресанту. см. первый комментарий к вопросу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, в tcpdump клиент периодически посылает пакеты на сервер опенвпн и пакеты приходят с сервера; периодически клиент отправляет пакеты на CPE-EG-SNR.lo.domain, честно говоря, я не знаю, что это такое. Судя по тому, что половина трафика все-таки проходит через сервер openvpn, я так понимаю, что интернет на клиенте все-таки должен быть, но почему-то нет(((

Comment: перечитал вопрос. понял, что вы не изложили главного: при чём тут вообще «интернет»? изложите схему вашей сети и маршрутизации в ней. приведите вывод `ip a; ip r` до включения openvpn и после. для исправления вопроса нажмите [edit] ниже текста вопроса.